# Boostrap Multiselect Z-index issue on Portlets

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, websphere-portal

We are using Bootstrap v3.3.6, and have employed Multiselect boxes.  We use IBM Portal Portlets for our site, and we have an issue with the multiselect with several options.

If the last multiselect (we often have several on a page) for a user has 5 or more items to choose from (database supplied), anything past 4 is not shown, based on the amount of space at the bottom of the Portlet.  There are buttons there, which allows for some space.

I can add a couple of line breaks before the buttons to allow the fifth item to show - which is not ideal, but it's a bandaid for now - but I am more concerned about future users that may have more than five options.

The z-index on this is 1000, and everything else on the page is less than that.  It seems its the portlet itself that is limiting the display.

The site is heavily css driven, so I have tried overflow: visible, overflow-y: visible, and have added these to enclosing divs, sections, etc on the site.  Even overflow-y: scroll won't work, since you can't see the bottom of the dropdown to see the down scroll.

I'm just wondering if anyone has any experience with this (especially with websphere portal) and has any suggestions.

[image: Only four options shown]

```
.dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: none;
  min-width: 160px;
  margin: 2px 0 0;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  border-radius: 1px;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175);
  background-clip: padding-box;
}
```

This is the actual multi-select table cell (sorry I had to obfuscate the real options - it's a privacy kind of thing):

```
          <script type="text/javascript">var eServices184141 = [];</script>
          <select id="184141-SERVICES" multiple="multiple" onchange="serviceSelected(eServices184141, 184141, this);accountUpdated('184141');" style="display: none;">
             <script type="text/javascript">eServices184141.push('BILLDETAILS');</script>
            <option id="OPT1184141" value="OPT1" selected="">OPT1</option>
            <option id="OPT2184141" value="OPT2">OPT2</option>
            <script type="text/javascript">opt184141.push('opt');</script>
            <option id="OPT3184141" value="OPT3" selected="">OPT3</option>
             <script type="text/javascript">opt184141.push('opt');</script>
             <option id="OPT4184141" value="OPT4" selected="">OPT4</option>
             <script type="text/javascript">opt184141.push('opt');</script>
             <option id="OPT5184141" value="OPT5" selected="">OPT5</option>

      </select><div class="btn-group"><button type="button" class="multiselect dropdown-toggle btn btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" title="options" aria-expanded="false"><span class="multiselect-selected-text">4 selected</span> <b class="caret"></b></button><ul class="multiselect-container dropdown-menu"><li class="active"><a tabindex="0"><input type="checkbox" id="idOPT1184141" value="OPT1"><label class="checkbox" for="idOPT1184141"></label>OPT1</a></li><li><a tabindex="0"><input type="checkbox" id="idOPT2184141" value="OPT2"><label class="checkbox" for="idOPT2184141"></label> OPT2</a></li><li class="active"><a tabindex="0"><input type="checkbox" id="idOPT3184141" value="OPT3"><label class="checkbox" for="idOPT3184141"></label> OPT3</a></li><li class="active"><a tabindex="0"><input type="checkbox" id="idOPT4184141" value="OPT4"><label class="checkbox" for="idOPT4184141"></label> OPT4</a></li><li class="active"><a tabindex="0"><input type="checkbox" id="idOPT5184141" value="OPT5"><label class="checkbox" for="idOPT5184141"></label> OPT5</a></li></ul></div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
           $(document).ready(function() {
              $("#184141-SERVICES").multiselect({
                 numberDisplayed: 1
              });
           });
        </script>
```

Comment: Is this the last one on the page and bumping up against the bottom of the page? can you tell it to scroll  through the options maybe with what was suggested here https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/issues/1 .dropdown-menu {
max-height: 500px;
overflow-y: auto;
overflow-x: hidden;
}

Comment: Unfortunately, that suggestion doesn't work.  I have added the CSS we use for "dropdown-menu".  I'm starting to wonder if there's a calc function that maybe, based on child elements, will move up the "dropdown".  It is not the bottom of the page it hits, but appears to be the bottom of the portlet.  There are other portlets below this one.

Comment: can you also show what your markup looks like for the multi-select? this also might help https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/issues/382

Comment: I added that markup.  It's big, but that's all due to how it is pulled from a database with a lot of other bulky pieces of information.

Comment: The problem may with using position absolute and it is now causing the div it is in(the portlet to grow) when it grows I think you might need to change it to relitive . See this example http://formvalidation.io/examples/bootstrap-multiselect/

Comment: Yes, thank you.  That was my temporary solution, although not completely ideal.  We may have it solved now however.  There was a layout piece for the portal called wpthemeOverflowAuto that had the style overflow: hidden;.  We have changed that to : visible; and we are testing to make sure we didn't break anything else.  But so far, it works, and extends the full length, with all options showing.  Thanks!

Comment: yeah that one is a pain and most of the time does not cause any problem changing, but can cause problems with some of the inline editing features